# How to make a play again method?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a game where when it ends, a gameover image (gameoverscreen.png) is visible (formerly hidden), and a button appears to play again. What I tried doing was creating a IBAction for it, then in that action, reloading the viewDidLoad.

example:

```
 -(IBAction)restartGame:(id)sender{

     [self viewDidLoad]; //to reload the screen
     gameoverscreen.hidden = YES; 
     replayButton.hidden = YES; 

 }
```

I thought this would reload the screen, but it simply appears for half a second, then the gameoverscreen is visible again. I thought it had something to do with my NSTimer, but the timer is invalidated when the `gameoverscreen.hidden = NO;` so its not that.. Any reason on why it won't reload the screen properly, and allow the user to play again?

Comment: "Any reason on why...?"  Yes.  Lots of reasons.  Starting with calling `viewDidLoad` manually is an extraordinarily bad idea.  But the most likely cause is that the `restartGame:` method isn't even being called at all.

Comment: we can't know that... certainly not from what you have given us... that could be perfectly valid.

Comment: well yeah probably not perfectly valid

Comment: @nhgrif where would I call the method?

Comment: @GradyPlayer what extra info do you need? I can supply

Comment: is this a game using some framework? what the lifecycle like? we don't know anything about your game...

Comment: What method?  If `viewDidLoad`, then NO WHERE.  You shouldn't call it manually.  If `restartGame:`, then you should call it whenever you need it... but I'm not certain it's actually being called.

Comment: @GradyPlayer i didn't add any frameworks for the game because its an extremely simple game, the entire game is based on RectIntersectsRects and an NSTimer and a score, (just a ball bouncing type of game)

Comment: Hmm ok, @nhgrif these are good tips. Sorry this is a practice app so i'm just trying to practice Objective-C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I can't answer the question per se but I can give advice... this is what I imagine your starting code looks like...

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad
 {
     NSTimer *t = [some timer code to start the loop and process events]
     //init some other state stuff, arrays of rects etc.
 }

 -(IBAction)restartGame:(id)sender{

     [self viewDidLoad]; //to reload the screen
     gameoverscreen.hidden = YES; 
     replayButton.hidden = YES; 

 }
```

this is what your code should look like:

```
 -(void)viewDidLoad
 {
     [self restartGame];

 }
- (void)setUpInitalGameState
{
     //init some other state stuff, arrays of rects etc.
}
- (void)start
{
     NSTimer *t = [some timer code to start the loop and process events]


}

 -(IBAction)restartGame:(id)sender{

     [self setUpInitialGameState];
     [self start];
 }
```

Comment: well @ShenHutah I hope it helps, keep at it, all of this view lifecycle stuff is hard at first, but it will click for you...

Answer (score 1):

You should not be calling viewDidLoad to reset your game to a starting state. Let viewDidLoad only be called once automatically when the application launches, and then manually reset the variables and positions in your game. In viewDidLoad, you should load any images, audio, and initialize variables used in your games. Handle your game reset in a separate function with a format similar to the one below:

```
(IBAction)resetGame:(id)sender{

    // Set positions of all images to a starting state.

    // Change image visibilities as desired.

    // Reset all game variables to the initial state.
}
```

My iOS game SlothDrop only calls viewDidLoad once. When the game ends, all objects are animated off screen and are repositioned, where they are later animated back on screen. At no time is the view loaded again, all objects are just moved around. You can see how I reset the game in the free version here: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/slothdrop-free/id789603341?mt=8&uo=4

Answer (score -1):

In this way you need wholly re-init your controller and then push it to the screen.

Comment: You certainly don't.  In fact, this would be very problematic, as now he's adding a whole new instance of this view controller every time the player wants to start a new game...